# javascript show-hide an element in specific time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to know if it possible to show and hide an element at a specific time in o´clock ?
Let´s say I want the div show up everyday from 20:00 until 07:00.

**Here is what I tried but I lack some lines which I have no idea for that. Please help.**

```
function myTimer() {
    var d = new Date();
    document.getElementById("MyTime").innerHTML = d.toLocaleTimeString();
}



$( document ).ready(function() {
myTimer();
show_hide_me();
});


function show_hide_me () {

   <------HERE START TO SHOW/ HIDE (I don´t know how to do it more)
    ("#MyElm")
    if the time between 20:00 - 07:00 show();
    else hide();
    }

 }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
var date = new Date();
var currentHours = date.getHours();
currentHours = ("0" + currentHours).slice(-2);
alert(currentHours);
if (currentHours > 20 || currentHours < 7){        
  $('#myElem').show();
} 
else 
{
  $('#myElem').hide();
}
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/f349k/1/

Comment: This cannot work `(currentHours > 20 && currentHours < 7)` will always evaluate to false.

Comment: This answer is flawed if you want a specific time in a specific timezone. Like a store in EST would not be open when it is daytime in AEST. So better to use getUTCHours and base the time off that.

Answer (score 4):

```
function show_hide_me () {
  var myDate = new Date();
  var hours = myDate.getHours();
    if (hours > 20 || hours < 7){
       $('#myElem').show();
    } else {
       $('#myElem').hide();
    }
 }

show_hide_me();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/wkhWK/

Comment: Hello and thank you for your help.
I have tried just now but it´s not work.
:S

Comment: Yes sorry there were some typos, I have fixed them now http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/wkhWK/

Comment: I´m so sorry to answer too late. Thank you for help :)